# Calculating difference with respect to previous day

Tags: r

```
Stock.Open <- c(102.25,102.87,102.25,100.87,103.44,103.87,103.00)
Stock.Close <- c(102.12,102.62,100.12,103.00,103.87,103.12,105.12)
day<-c(1:7)
df<-data.frame(day,Stock.Close,Stock.Open)
```

How to I calculate the %difference for stock.open and stock.close each day w.r.t to the previous day. 
Ex: I want to calculate %change in Stock.open between day1,day2 then day2,day3, day3,day4, and so on..

Comment: @d.b this is not the ratio of the difference on previous value, but on current value

Comment: @d.b https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120396/calculating-difference-with-respect-to-previous-day-for-each-id

Comment: @RavulaAbhigyan I suggest you edit your post back to your original example, select your favorite answer and accept it, and then ask a new question with the new level of complexity. When you changed your question, it makes our answers looked "wrong". It is also tedious and time-consuming for us to update our answers. Most importantly, we certainly do not have this responsibility to update our answers when our answers are valid for your original example.

Comment: @RavulaAbhigyan I just realized you have already asked the new question but did not change this post. If you don't mind, I am going to do it for you. Next time, please think about your example and question carefully before you post, it will make you get the help you need more efficiently, and also make others easier to help you.

Comment: @RavulaAbhigyan Please consider accepting one answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

EDITED :

previous solution had a ratio computed on current value, not previous value (see edit history)

updated solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% bind_cols(map(df[2:3],~c(NA,diff(.x))/lag(.x)))
#   day Stock.Close Stock.Open Stock.Close1  Stock.Open1
# 1   1      102.12     102.25           NA           NA
# 2   2      102.62     102.87  0.004896201  0.006063570
# 3   3      100.12     102.25 -0.024361723 -0.006027024
# 4   4      103.00     100.87  0.028765481 -0.013496333
# 5   5      103.87     103.44  0.008446602  0.025478338
# 6   6      103.12     103.87 -0.007220564  0.004156999
# 7   7      105.12     103.00  0.019394880 -0.008375854
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quantmod::Delt`

```
library(quantmod)
Delt(Stock.Open)

     Delt.1.arithmetic
[1,]                NA
[2,]       0.006063570
[3,]      -0.006027024
[4,]      -0.013496333
[5,]       0.025478338
[6,]       0.004156999
[7,]      -0.008375854

Delt(Stock.Close)

     Delt.1.arithmetic
[1,]                NA
[2,]       0.004896201
[3,]      -0.024361723
[4,]       0.028765481
[5,]       0.008446602
[6,]      -0.007220564
[7,]       0.019394880
```

You can also calculate open-to-close percentage change with

```
Delt(Stock.Open, Stock.Close)

     Delt.0.arithmetic
[1,]      -0.001271394
[2,]      -0.002430252
[3,]      -0.020831296
[4,]       0.021116288
[5,]       0.004156999
[6,]      -0.007220564
[7,]       0.020582524
```

As **Moody_Mudskipper** points out, you can add the results to your existing data frame with

```
# purrr
library(purrr)
df[4:5] <- map(df[2:3],Delt)

# base R
df[4:5] <- Map(Delt, df[2:3])
```

To obtain the day-to-day percent change in open-to-close percent change

```
df$ans <- Delt(Stock.Open, Stock.Close) / lag(Delt(Stock.Open, Stock.Close))

  day Stock.Close Stock.Open Delt.0.arithmetic
1   1      102.12     102.25                NA
2   2      102.62     102.87         1.9114865
3   3      100.12     102.25         8.5716616
4   4      103.00     100.87        -1.0136810
5   5      103.87     103.44         0.1968622
6   6      103.12     103.87        -1.7369655
7   7      105.12     103.00        -2.8505424
```

Comment: so `df[4:5]<-map(df[2:3],Delt)` to get same output as other solutions, it's actually the shortest and more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea, using functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `lag` can shift the values, the default is one. Once each row is ready, we can calculate the percentage change using `mutate`. `replace_na` is one way to replace the `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Pre.Open = lag(Stock.Open)) %>%
  mutate(Percent.Change = (Stock.Open - Pre.Open) / Pre.Open * 100) %>%
  replace_na(list(Percent.Change = 0))
df2
  day Stock.Close Stock.Open Pre.Open Percent.Change
1   1      102.12     102.25       NA      0.0000000
2   2      102.62     102.87   102.25      0.6063570
3   3      100.12     102.25   102.87     -0.6027024
4   4      103.00     100.87   102.25     -1.3496333
5   5      103.87     103.44   100.87      2.5478338
6   6      103.12     103.87   103.44      0.4156999
7   7      105.12     103.00   103.87     -0.8375854
```

#### Update

If you want to calculate both the `Stock.Open` and `Stock.Close` percentage change, you can use the following code.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Stock")), funs(Percent = (. - lag(.))/lag(.) * 100)) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
df2
  day Stock.Close Stock.Open Stock.Close_Percent Stock.Open_Percent
1   1      102.12     102.25           0.0000000          0.0000000
2   2      102.62     102.87           0.4896201          0.6063570
3   3      100.12     102.25          -2.4361723         -0.6027024
4   4      103.00     100.87           2.8765481         -1.3496333
5   5      103.87     103.44           0.8446602          2.5478338
6   6      103.12     103.87          -0.7220564          0.4156999
7   7      105.12     103.00           1.9394880         -0.8375854
```

Answer (score 0):

The second shortest solution (and without external libraries):

```
df$relDiff.Stock.Open = c(NA,diff(df$Stock.Open,lag=1))/df$Stock.Open*100
df$relDiff.Stock.Close = c(NA,diff(df$Stock.Close,lag=1))/df$Stock.Close*100
```

Result

```
  day Stock.Close Stock.Open relDiff.Stock.Open relDiff.Stock.Close
1   1      102.12     102.25                 NA                  NA
2   2      102.62     102.87          0.6027024           0.4872345
3   3      100.12     102.25         -0.6063570          -2.4970036
4   4      103.00     100.87         -1.3680976           2.7961165
5   5      103.87     103.44          2.4845321           0.8375854
6   6      103.12     103.87          0.4139790          -0.7273080
7   7      105.12     103.00         -0.8446602           1.9025875
```

Answer (score 0):

Very nice functionality in dplyr, lag and lead. You can also use data.table package.

`library(dplyr)
 df <- df %>% mutate(Diff.Previous = Stock.Open - lag(Stock.Close) )
 df`

```
  day Stock.Close Stock.Open Diff.Previous
1   1      102.12     102.25            NA
2   2      102.62     102.87          0.75
3   3      100.12     102.25         -0.37
4   4      103.00     100.87          0.75
5   5      103.87     103.44          0.44
6   6      103.12     103.87          0.00
```

Comment: However OP wants a ratio so you don't answer the question

Comment: Oh, yes. Not the answer. I also not carefully read the original question. Only thought I can help and lag shift is really nice. The rest is now easy. But anyway ycw answered faster.